# express response with a callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, callback

Is it possible to send a response from express, and wait for a return response before continuing?

A typical scenario is something like this

Server A sends a request to server B.
Server B processes the request and sends to back to server A 
Server B waits for a response from server A before continuing 
Server A does further processing of the response from Server B and sends it back to Server B
Server B then handles the rest of the processing required.

My understanding is that normally this is handled with callbacks.  In express I would expect to do something like

`res.write('response', callback);`

```
function callback() {
    //do stuff
}
```

I don't see that this is possible with the res.write method though.  Is there another method I can use with express to get this functionality?  I've never used `socket.io` before, but this seems like a scenario where websockets would be useful.  Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: You could pipe the response from server B to server A, like `serverBResponse.pipe(serverAResponse)` and voila! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
res.on('finish', callback);
```

is sent when the last of the data is given to the OS to deal with.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish

If you need to know when the client receives/processes the data, however, the client must send something back to the server, in which case socket.io could help.

Comment: Thanks Josh,  I do need to know when the client has processed the data and what information it can send back to me.  I'll look into socket.io.  Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the responses and help from everyone, I ended up using sessions to get what I needed.

```
var session = require('express-session');
```

Thanks again